# How To Select Auto Suggestion Address In Dropdown Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, autosuggest

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

# Removes SSL Issues With Chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('log-level=3') 
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
#options.add_argument('--headless') # Comment to view browser actions

# Initiate Chrome Driver
url = 'https://www.dunelm.com/product/caldonia-check-natural-eyelet-curtains-1000187301'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe",options=options)
#driver.implicitly_wait(10) # Global Wait Settings
driver.get(url)

# Accept Cookie Popup
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[2]/button'))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Enter Curtain Size in Drop Drop
size = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'curtainSize')
select_size = Select(size)
select_size.select_by_visible_text('W 228cm (90") x D 182cm (72") - £170')

# Click 'Check in Local Store'
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="product-top-wrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div'))).click()
 
# Enter Postcode or Location
postcode = "Aylesbury HP19 8BU, UK"
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div/div/input'))).send_keys(postcode)

#driver.close()
```

**URL**: https://www.dunelm.com/product/caldonia-check-natural-eyelet-curtains-1000187301

The above script utilizes **Selenium** and is aimed at automating the process of:

- Launching the above url
- Accepting the cookie popup
- Selecting the curtain size
- Clicking text link 'Check in Local Store'
- Enter postcode or location

## Issue

[image]

I'm unable to proceed beyond this point as I **do not know what is required to accept the address details entered as an auto suggestion**.
I tried using the code below without success

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div/div/input'))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to press enter, after you copy the address into address bar. There are multiple ways to do it. The below solution is demonstrating `ActionsChain, key press`

**Code:-**

```
# Enter Postcode or Location
postcode = "Aylesbury HP19 8BU, UK"
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div/div/input'))).send_keys(postcode)

time.sleep(5)
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.RETURN).pause(2).key_up(Keys.RETURN).perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: What if there will be there multiple auto suggested options while you will not be able to know how many and will not know the order of the desired option between all the suggested option?

Comment: See OP already, knows the address in advance, read this line `I'm unable to proceed beyond this point as I do not know what is required to accept the address` for that I have given solution for the exact issue.

Comment: I see. However you should preferable give more generic answer that will be useful in other cases too.

Comment: Hi cruisepandey, thank you for the awesome timely response. With the addition of "from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains" the solution worked a treat.